# Why Accessorized fields are required when fetch a unAccessorized fields in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Suppose I have a `Homework` Eloquent model like this :

```
class Homework extends Model
    {
        protected $primaryKey = 'homework_id';
        protected $dates      = ['deadline'];
        protected $appends    = ['deadline_picker'];

        protected $fillable = ['lesson_id', 'teacher', 'title', 'desc', 'deadline', 'address', 'size', 'type'];


        public function getDeadlineAttribute ($value)
        {
            return date('d/m/Y H:i', strtotime($value));
        }

        public function getDeadlinePickerAttribute ()
        {
             return date('l d F Y-H:i', strtotime($this->attributes['deadline']));
        }
}
```

As you see I define a new **Accessor** (`deadline_picker`) for `deadline` field.

Now I want to select only `title` of this model like this :

```
public function Homeworks ()
{
    $homeworks =
    Homework::where('deadline', '>=', Carbon::now())->get(['title']);

    return $homeworks;

    //return view('pages/homeworks', compact('homeworks'));
}
```

But after running above code, bellow error is shown:

```
ErrorException in Homework.php line 30:
Undefined index: deadline
```

Seems that in this case, getting `deadline` field in `->get(['title']);` is required (means `->get(['title','deadline']);`).

Why it happens?

Comment: Because you explicitly told laravel it to `select` only `title` from the DB. And use date mutators, they will make your life a lot easier: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you've only selected the `title` attribute out of the database, but your accessor is expecting `deadline` to always exist too. The reason for this is because when you're returning `$homeworks` out of your controller, Laravel is converting the models into json (or similar) using the `->toArray()` or `->toJson()` methods on your model, which is calling your accessor.

You have 2 options, you can either always pull `deadline` out of the database reguardless of whether you actually want it or not, or you can add an `is_null()` check to your accessor, something similar to below

```
public function getDeadlinePickerAttribute()
{
    return is_null($this->deadline) ? null : date('l d F Y-H:i', strtotime($this->deadline));
}
```

Theres one more improvement you could make, as you've supplied the `deadline` attribute on the `$dates` property of your model, Eloquent will automatically convert this into a Carbon object allowing you to easily manipulate the date without using `strtotime()` or any of those nasty older date handling functions.

```
public function getDeadlinePickerAttribute()
{
    return $this->deadline instanceof Carbon ? $this->deadline->format('l d F Y-H:i') : null;
}
```

More on Carbon http://carbon.nesbot.com/ and date mutators https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators